# Posting unicode data using HttpClient

Tags: c#, unicode, encoding, httpclient

I am trying to post some unicode data using Http request message. Somehow content encoding is causing some issue. I am not setting any encoding explicitly in my code.

For example, I am trying to send 'รัค' & on client side it is being received as 'à¸£à¸±à¸'.

**Sample code**

```
var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = cookieContainer, })
using(var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler)){

    //set all cookies
    foreach (var obj in configurationData["request_cookies"])
    {
        var cookie = ((JProperty)(obj));
        cookieContainer.Add(new Uri(configurationData["request_cookie_base_url"].ToString()),
            new Cookie(cookie.Name, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(cookie.Value.ToString())));
    }

    var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
    request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
    request.RequestUri = new Uri(configurationData["form_url"].ToString());

    //set all request headers
    foreach (var obj in configurationData["request_headers"])
    {
        var cookie = ((JProperty) (obj));
        request.Headers.Add(cookie.Name, cookie.Value.ToString());
    }
    request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));

    //get request content data from configurationData as keyvalue pair
    var contentValue = parsedCrmConfigurationData["form_data_template"]
                        .ToObject<Dictionary<string, string>>();

    request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(contentValue);

    var response = httpClient.SendAsync(request).Result;
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
}
```

Do I need to pass encoding specifically? if yes then how? 

Please help me understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code to encode your content

```
private static HttpContent getencodedContent(string jsonString)
        {
            var cont = new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            return cont;
        }
```

Comment: I want to simulate web form post request using C# code. Are you sure I should use 'application/json' content type instead of 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' ?

Comment: you can also use application/x-www-form-urlencoded instead of application/json